# Convergence rate of a series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What is convergence rate of a series

$  
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^\alpha
\\ $

where $\alpha< -1$ ? For example, for $\alpha=-1$ it equals to $O(\log n)$.

Comment: It's more like $O(\log N)$ where you sum the first $N$ values. Summing to infinity results (in the case of $\alpha = -1$) in a diverging series.

Comment: thanks, for pointing, have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer contains a mistake. The difference between the series and the integral is actually not negligible.

First of all, it is correct to say that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha = O(1)$, because as $n \to \infty$, the series *converges* when $\alpha < -1$.

If you want to know a more precise asymptotic formula, you can use the following: First of all, note that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^\alpha = \zeta(-\alpha)$, where $\zeta$ is the [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). Then use the fact that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^\alpha - \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty k^\alpha = \zeta(-\alpha) - \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty k^\alpha$$

so our task is to find the rate of decay of $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty k^\alpha$. One simple way to do this is to compare this sum to the integral $\int_{k=n}^\infty x^\alpha dx$. This graph should explain why this works: The sum gives you the blue region, while the integral gives you the green region (in the graph, $n=1$).

[image: Graph of 1/x^2 and 1/k^2]

So, we have:
$$0 \le \sum _{k=n+1}^\infty k^\alpha \le \int_{k=n}^\infty x^\alpha dx = - \frac {n^{\alpha + 1}} {\alpha + 1}$$

This means:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha = \zeta(-\alpha) + O\left(n^{\alpha + 1}\right)$$

You can get further terms by using [Abel's summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) to convert the sum $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty k^\alpha$ to an integral, and repeat as much as you want (and can, based on $\alpha$) using integration by parts.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** This answer was wrong. I posted a new answer, and I'm keeping this for the comments.

Comment: I have showed it, then the integral equals to $\frac{1}{(\alpha +1)}(N^{\alpha+1}-1)$. So we obtain $\sum_{n=1}^N n^\alpha=O(N^{\alpha+1} -1)$. Is it right?

Comment: That's the same as $O(1)$ which is just saying the series converges. Usually in the case of convergence, if you want to say something about asymptotics, you say it about the next terms, i.e. $\frac 1 {\alpha+1} + O(\ldots)$.

Comment: so it is gonna be $\frac{1}{\alpha +1}+ O(N^{\alpha+1})$, right? Sorry,I am not good in asymptotics.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake. In fact the difference is negligible only when $\alpha \ge -1$. When $\alpha < -1$ the difference is not negligible, as the sum converges to the Riemann Zeta function so the main term is $\zeta(-\alpha)$. Analysis of the asymptotics requires analysis of the zeta function, and not the way I wrote it. Oops :(

Comment: Anyway, it would be correct to say that this is $O(1)$ since the series converges.